# Visual Studio 2013 removing 2012 guid from project mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I'm working with an asp.net mvc4 project that we've we've created in Visual Studio 2012.
I've opened it with vs2013, and it's removed an entry in  from the project file,  "{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}".  Googling around tells me that this guid represents MVC4.

Is it safe for me to move to vs2013 while my colleague is still on vs2012 with no vs2013 install? (Will it break backwards compatibility?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will hurt backwards compatibility. If your colleague opens the project she might miss some MVC convenience features like "Add controller" but she can easily work around it.